# add multiple attributes to NSAttributedString and encode HTML

Tags: text, encode, nsattributedstring

I want to encode a text to HTML and apply multiple attributes at the same time.

My Swift 4 code looks like this:

```
let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
                data: tweetContent.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                documentAttributes: nil)

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.4

let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 17.0)!,
                NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]

let textRangeForFont : NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString!.length)
attributedString?.addAttributes(attributes, range: textRangeForFont)
```

`tweetContent` represents the string that I want to set a font for and which should be encoded for HTML. In the end, I want to set as many attributes as I like to that string without loosing the html encoding.

However, this code results in displaying the placeholder text which I set up in the storyboard.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to add the attributed text to the textview:

```
textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

This solved my problem.